# How do I find my associated EpicGames account details?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale, epic-games-launcher

I recently started playing Fortnite on the Xbox, and as well as the PC. I currently have 2 separate accounts, 1 for PC and 1 for xbox. I know the email/password I use for my PC account.

With Fortnite now allowing cross progression, I want to connect my xbox live to my PC's EpicGames account. Unfortunately to do this, I need to disconnect my xbox from it's current EpicGames account.

I have tried logging in using my xbox credentials but it does not work. Trying to "forget password" has a "Email sent" for any garbage email in the correct format so I am unable to test with email it would have originally gone under.

My goal is to be able to login to my EpicGames account and disconnect my xbox live.

How can I find my credentials for the EpicGames account created with my xbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to merge your accounts. A quick google search comes up with the official tutorial - far better than I could explain.

https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/news/account-linking-steps